# Give active split all of screen besides 5 lines for inactive splits

Tags: vim

**edit**
Answer provided

I'm trying to split my window in vim by running the following:

```
:sp
```

The desired behaviour I'm trying to achieve is to limit the inactive split to five lines while giving the active split the rest of the screen

I've put the following in my `.vimrc`

```
 set winheight=40¬                                                                    
 set winminheight=5¬
```

it will preserve the 5 lines in the alt splits. The problem is I resized the window to check if it would work. It does but If my screen is more than `45 lines` the behaviour is broken.

What would specifically answer my problem would be a way to preserve the 5 lines in alt splits while giving the active split the rest of the screen.

Any info would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set winheight=5
Set winminheight=5
Set winheight=999
```

If winheight is set too big before setting winminheight it will break the desired output.

Setting an arbitrary low value fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

To keep 4 lines in non-active windows:

```
:set winminheight=4
```

To always maximize the current window to a height of 79:

```
:autocmd WinEnter * setlocal winheight=79
```

You can also supply a higher number (`999`) to give it the maximum possible. This is called *Rolodex mode*.

Unfortunately, the two cannot be easily combined.

Comment: when I set winminheight it complains it cant be less than winheight. setting winheight works fine as long as there's enough room on the screen. I'm updating my question now.